# Printing to stdout with HiveQL

Tags: apache-pig, hiveql

I'm currently in the process of learning how to use hive with Amazon's Elastic Data Pipeline technology. I'd like to print out the results of various parts of my hive script to stdout but can't seem to figure out how to do so. I know that with Pig there's a `DUMP` command which dumps a table to stdout.

Is there a hive equivalent to Pig's `DUMP`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. I googled a little bit harder after posting this and found `SHOW`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Show

EDIT: `SHOW` let me display the columns for debugging purposes but I can't figure out how to dump the contents of a table to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Just making a **SELECT** in your script will print the results to the standard output.

:)